# Why is the span line-height being ignored?

Tags: html

I have the following code:

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 350px">
  <span style="line-height: 1.1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </span>
</div>
```

This results in a `line-height: 1.5`. Why? Shouldn't it be 1.1 as defined in the `<span>`? The dev tools even show a struck through body line-height.
[image: struck through body line-height]
For me, it is even stranger: Every span line-height smaller than 1.5 (like my 1.1) is being ignored but values greater than 1.5 are being applied to the span. Why?
[image: large line-height being applied]

I can resolve this problem by setting the `line-height: 1.1` to the surrounding `<div>`. Again the question: Why?

Comment: Because it would not make much sense, if an inline element could _lower_ the line height, I suppose? Your span just happens to be the _only_ content of your parent element here - but that must not always the case, there could be text content outside of the span. So imagine you had some text from your div first, then the span content started on that same line, that same span content breaks into the next line, and is then followed by more content of the div itself on that same second line.  So what _could_ a "lower line height" for the span now even _look like_ ...?

Comment: That makes sense, but isn't it also true for greater line heights? And greater line-heights work.

Comment: A greater line height can increase the line-height of the surrounding content as well. Consider this example: https://jsfiddle.net/oxf5v6jp/ The higher line height of the span content (red) increases the line height where necessary, whereas for the rest of the div content, it stays as it is. This won't work the other way around for a lower line height, because then the div content before and after the span text could start to overlap and become unreadable.

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks a lot. If you want to summarize this in an answer, I accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Again the question: Why?

Because it would not make much sense, if an inline element could *lower* the line height, I suppose? Your span just happens to be the only content of your parent element here - but that must not always the case, there could be text content outside of the span. So imagine you had some text from your div first, then the span content started on that same line, that same span content breaks into the next line, and is then followed by more content of the div itself on that same second line. So what could a "lower line height" for the span now even *look like* ...?

> but isn't it also true for greater line heights? And greater line-heights work.

Consider the following example:

```css
div { line-height: 1.1; width:20em; }
span { line-height: 3; color: red; }
```

```html
<div>
lorem ipsum dolor sit ahmet lorem ipsum dolor sit ahmet lorem ipsum dolor sit ahmet lorem ipsum dolor sit ahmet <span>lorem ipsum dolor sit ahmet</span> lorem ipsum dolor sit ahmet lorem ipsum dolor sit ahmet lorem ipsum dolor sit ahmet lorem ipsum dolor sit ahmet
</div>
```

The higher line height of the span content (red) increases the line height where necessary, whereas for the rest of the div content, it stays as it is. This won't work the other way around for a lower line height, because then the div content before and after the span text could start to overlap and become unreadable.